# Reading a linked XML file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

In the `<head>` section of my `HTML` document, I have linked an `XML` file:

```
<link id="data" type="text/xml" href="Data.xml" />
```

I would like to read the contents of this file via JavaScript, but I can't even seem to get access to the contents of the file.

I tested it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = document.getElementById("data");
    document.write(link.innerText);
    document.close();
</script>
```

What should I try next?

*P.S. ...Can't use AJAX for this since it's all local files.*

Comment: If it's all local files, and you're on Windows, then you could create an HTA and load the XML via MSXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link doesn't have a `rel` attribute, so the browser doesn't do anything with the URL (not that any value for `rel` means "Download and make it available to JS").

It doesn't have any `innerText` because it is an element defined as being empty. It exists only for the attributes it has on it.

You'll need to get the URL by using `getAttribute` and then fetch the data using an `XMLHttpRequest` object (i.e. Ajax).

The usual security restrictions for local files will apply. So you'll need to use a browser that supports access to them via XMLHttpRequest or install a local web server.